# Como llamar un conteo de base de datos con un Servicio Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statements

Estoy tratando de mostrar un conteo de mi base de datos pero el servicio no me esta trayendo nada y no estoy seguro del porqué. Probe cambiando en el POJO el tipo a INT pero no funcionó. Sé que este metodo funciona cuando le solicito que me traiga otros datos especificos como el ID o el tipo, pero en este caso que es un conteo hecho por la base de datos no se si debe ser diferente

Este es el codigo:

```
public class HomePendientesDAO {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HomePendientesDAO.class);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public List<DatosCausaPojo> getListaUltimosPendientes() {
    try {
        List<DatosCausaPojo> listaCuenta = new ArrayList<>();
        String query = "SELECT COUNT (cte.id)\n"+
                       "FROM sgc_causa_temp cte\n"+
                       "WHERE cte.enviada = TRUE;\n"+ 
                        "SELECT COUNT(cau.id)\n"+
                        "FROM sgc_causa cau\n"+
                        "WHERE cau.id IN (\n"+
                        "SELECT uca.id_causa\n"+
                        "FROM sgc_usuario_causa uca,\n"+
                        "     sgc_usuario usu\n"+
                        "WHERE cau.id = uca.id_causa\n"+
                        "AND usu.id = uca.id_usuario\n"+
                        "AND (usu.id_perfil = 1)\n"+
                        ")";
        LOGGER.info(query);
        Connection conn = new BDConexion().conectaPostgreSql();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            DatosCausaPojo dto = new DatosCausaPojo();
            dto.setCantidadCausa(rs.getString(1));
            listaCuenta.add(dto);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
        return listaCuenta;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: veo que haces varias consultas, deberias de hacer solamente una consulta SQL por prepared statement

Comment: Como? :o disculpa, soy super nuevo en el ambito por lo que no estoy seguro de como podria formularlo

Comment: haz una sola consulta, las consultas terminan donde pones un `;`